# How to connect to wifi on a Gnome 2.24.1 system?

Tags: networking, rhel, gnome, wifi

A friend gave me an old laptop running Gnome 2.24.1. It's been in storage for years but seems to run fine, albeit with this old OS. Now, I don't know too much about Linux, but I'd like to set it up for my Mum to use at home. The first problem I've run into is that I don't see how to get it to connect to the wireless internet. There are some networking applications, but they're asking about SSID and Ethernet and all that stuff. Is there any way to get it to auto-detect our wifi at home? I guess once it's connected it's going to want to get updates after all these years, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what version of Red Hat you're using, you can check like this:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 19 (Schrödinger’s Cat)
```

You likely have some old version of Fedora on it. Perhaps Fedora Core 5 or 6 with that version of GNOME.

In those ancient versions I believe they came with a version of NetworkManager. There's typically a GUI for it in the upper right menu bar. You'll need to put your WPA network's SSID & Passphrase into this applet's dialogs. Try left or right clicking on this applet to gain access to it.

#### applet

[image: ss of networkmanager]

#### configuration dialog

[image: ss #2]

I'd also encourage you to download a more modern version of Fedora (it's up to 20 now)! There has been tremendous advancements since GNOME 2.24 and much of the  software will likely make the setting up of the WiFi much easier. As I recall, with GNOME 2.24, getting WiFi and other things on a laptop could be fairly tricky at times.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! It's Fedora 10 but I don't see any NetworkManager. I did find some other network config stuff, but it seems to be hosed. I'll download the latest version and try and install it over USB stick. Hopefully the latest versions aren't too heavy for an old laptop like this!

Comment: If you find that GNOME is too demanding you can try XFCE as a desktop. Very usable and it's much less demanding on the resources.